# how to programmatically clear TextInput using useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to automatically clear the `TextInput` after the form has been submitted using `useRef`.

```js
const inputRef = useRef()
```

This shows a list of properties. However, following does not work:

```js
    const clearInput = () => {
        inputRef.current.value = ""
    }
```

It shows that `value` does not exist.

I'm currently using [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete):

```js
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    ref={inputRef}
    placeholder='Search'
    minLength={1}
    autoFocus={false}
    returnKeyType={'search'} 
    keyboardAppearance={'light'} /keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
    listViewDisplayed={focus}   
    fetchDetails={true}
    textContentType={'fullStreetAddress'}
    autoCapitalize={'words'}
    selectionColor={'red'}
    clearButtonMode={'always'}
    // other properties
/>
```

Comment: Can you show the component that "inputRef" refers to? That should work, so I assume you've done something wrong setting up the ref.

Comment: I'm using `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` [Inline Link](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete ) and it's based on `TextInput`. I'll update the answer

Comment: I took a quick look at the code for [GooglePlacesAutocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js) They refer to the text input in the code with `this.refs.textInput` so you should be able to get the text input ref with... `inputRef.refs.textInput` because inputRef doesn't refer to the text input, but the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` component, which has the input ref contained within it.

Comment: How about using `useRef`? `inputRef.current.textInput` or `inputRef.textInput` did not work

Comment: try `inputRef.current.refs.textInput` or `inputRef.refs.textInput` you need to access the `refs` object of the autocomplete component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ref, `inputRef` doesn't refer to the text input, but the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` component instead. The text input inside that component is what you need a ref to.

If you look at [the code](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js) you can see that its ref is defined as `"textInput"` (line 717), and that it is selected by the autocomplete component with `this.refs.textInput` (line 166)

Considering this, you should be able to access the text input ref via the autocomplete component like this:

`inputRef.current.refs.textInput`

Comment: it says `undefined is not an object` for `inputRef.current.refs`

Comment: actually `addressRef.current && addressRef.current.refs.textInput` worked!

Comment: @Kevvv great! Yeah, often your code will get called before the ref is setup by react so that check is necessary so that it only tries once it exists.

Comment: How do I clear the input using this? `addressRef.current && addressRef.current.refs.textInput.value = ""` doesn't seem right. It results in undefined

Comment: try an if instead of &&. `if(addressRef.current) { addressRef.current.refs.textInput.value = "" }` I don't think you can set variables that way.

Comment: `if (addressRef.current) {
            addressRef.current.refs.textInput.clear()
        }` this ultimately worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  `inputRef.current?.clear();`